# D3 not creating duplicate charts when required and included in separate webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, module, webpack

So I have two webpack bundles which required the same module that involes d3 operations. However, although the two files are executed twice in different bundle, it's not creating d3 duplicate chart as it usually would.

```
//critical.js is being loaded first
const setupVis = require('./visualization/renderVis.js').setupVis
```

---

```
//delay.js is being loaded after everything critical is done
const test = require('./visualization/renderVis.js').test
```

---

```
//simplified renderVis.js
var margin,x,y,line,svg
margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
            width = 970 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,52])
        .range([0, width]);

y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,100])
        .range([height, 0]);

line = d3.line()
                .x(function(d,i) { 
                        return x(i+1); 
                })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d); });

svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let counter = 0;
console.log('------being executed------')
console.log(counter)

function setupVis(){
    // blah blah
}

function test(){
    // blah blah
}

exports.setupVis = setupVis
exports.test = test
```

Since these two files are being included in two different bundles, they are actually ran twice. I added a console.log to confirm that.

```
//console output
----being executed----
0
----being executed----
0
```

Creating duplicate charts is not what I want here. I am just curious why it isn't happening when I am working on it locally. Usually it would. I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vja5e487/2/) fake bundle example to show how duplicate charts are being created. The jsfiddle is working as I expected but on my local server, duplicate chart are not being created.

thanks for the help.

p.s if there is anything else wrong about how I require or export module or any other small coding habits, pls let me know

Comment: Well, I'm seeing two SVGs in your fiddle.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado in jsfiddle it's working, but on my local server it's not. I am not sure how to really demonstrate that case. it's not a big deal but I am just curious